# Chromium/Selenium - Change displayed date format on entrys

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, chrome-options

I use Selenium, Chromedriver and Chromium to access a website.
Now there is an entry field on this page.
If I don't enter a browser language, German is the default. Then I have to pass the date in the format (DDMMYYYY). When I open the browser with the argument co.add_argument ("- lang = en") I have to enter the date in the format YYYYMMDD. Now I want the browser to be in English and the date format to be (DDMMYYYY).

Thanks Tim

Comment: Why do you want it to be DDMMYYY? Can't you just parse the YYYYMMDD date yourself and then convert it into DDMMYYYY?

Comment: No, I also use the program for other countries. I want to enter the same date format for all countries.